# How to rig this character?

Tags: rigging, armature, external-applications

I have a model that I have been trying to rig for hours now. I kept getting errors in unity when I used a rig in Blender, so I ran the model through Mixamo. This also had bad results, as the model's arms are severely deformed. However, this model has the proper hierarchy, etc. in Unity so I figured I could just modify the rig in Bender (the rig from Mixamo) and everything would be good. However, while I think the rig looks okay in pose mode, as soon as it enters a pose other than rest, the arms deform again. Any ideas why this might be happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken: based on what you're saying, you need to change a setting in your bone menu so that this deformation doesn't happen. Un-tick the box that controls this function; moreover, it's highly important that bones are not only correctly placed, but have the right mesh parts parented to them. An example of such is if the model is rotated without updating the bones themselves to accommodate this change (which then comes down to parenting). Such will result in distortion (e.g., a bone is assigned to the other arm instead of the arm it sits on).

For more on the topic of bone deformation see here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/bones/properties/deform.html

And refer to this image for the deformation box:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helps. Going through the deorming process I realized I had made a mistake very early on in the model process which was causing me all my issues. Turns out my model was 'backwards' in the scene, ie. it was rotated 180 degrees. For some reason this caused the arms, and only the arms, to be completely twisted when rigged. This aspect is fixed, however now i'm still have weird issues with the shoulders. However I should be able to figure that part out.

Comment: I had to update my comment here (deleted previous one): I hope my answer is indeed useful or pointed you in the right direction, which is why I mentioned bone placement and parenting just in case. I think what happened was that your model was rotated, as you said, yet the assigned parts stayed as they were (weren't updated to the rotation). This created the wacky issue you had, I believe. Surely if your model is rotated, you definitely run into this problem. In any case, I'm happy to have been of help and I've updated my answer to help future members w/similar problems.